# Wikipedia multi language parser

Tags: javascript, parsing, wikipedia

I have simple Wikipedia parser (it's not actual parser that create AST, it's just bunch of replace that create different syntax) in JavaScript for jQuery Terminal (command wikipedia in [404 error page](https://terminal.jcubic.pl/404)).

The code fetch the articles from Wikipedia using API and display the articles in terminal. The problem I have is that I don't know how parse other languages. The parser was created for English but I've just added -l option and it work the same. Except there are output issue because of the language, e.g. on English Wikipedia there is `Category` but on Polish is `Kategoria`. 
Do you know any way to figure out those meta names for any language? Other keywords are `File` and `Plik`. And there are lot of languages, does creating a list of keywords for other wiki is the only way to figure out those names?

There is help article [Help:Category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Category) but polish translation is not `Kategoria` but `Kategorie` (plural), so I can't just use Help pages to figure out the translation. Also there are different templates (I'm not sure what to do with them). Is writing different parser for each language the only way to properly parse Wikipedia articles?

Comment: perhaps run the website thru Google Translate and work off a common language.

Comment: @JGFMK the problem is I don't want to translate the text I want the language from that Wiki but only get those meta names (like keywords in a language). If I have Polish wikipedia article about "Roger Penrose" I want that article (from that version of Wikipedia) not English article translated to Polish.

Comment: Sounds then like you might want a semantic parser of some kind. Without some screenshots it's hard to advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in localized versions of the namespaces, you can get those via the API, e.g. https://pl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces will give you the list of Polish namespaces (note that the set of namespaces is not necessarily the same in different Wikipedias).

More generally, most keyword translations are found in [`MessagesPl.php`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/master/languages/messages/MessagesPl.php) for MediaWiki core, and various alias files for extensions (e.g. [`Gadgets.namespaces.php`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Gadgets/blob/master/Gadgets.namespaces.php) and [`Gadgets.alias.php`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Gadgets/blob/master/Gadgets.alias.php) for the Gadgets extension), but given the large number of extensions in use, that's probably not much help.